# file chooser in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am very fresher in iPhone. i want to make a file chooser in iPhone.

This chooser should be able to choose file from anywhere means also other than resource folder.

You may provide some weblinks for this . Please help me in this matter.

I want to show all files and folders to show which are available in my device.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You cann't see files and directories anywhere on non-jailbreak devices. Only your App sandbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iPhone used sandboxing, this means that accessing files that are outside of the application's sandbox are extremely limited. Apple does not want apps to expose a filesystem, thus this isn't really possible.